# Solution for search and select Index in ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arrays, stored-procedures, arraylist

i Have a ArrayList
this Object( that is Person ) contains 3 fields, one is String, another is int, and another is its ID.
An Stored Procedure needs those three fields where he/she select the object in the ListView.
Now, i should get the ID of the selected Object.The ID is different from the ListView Index,how should i search this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the way, i stored the String of my Object into an ArrayList
and use the Index of another ArrayList<> to point the same row the other.(While they are filling out in the same loop, so they have the same index )

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what data type Person.ID is and I'm not 100% sure I understood the question... but I think what you're looking for is a linear search, something like:

```
public static Person getPersonFromList(List<Person> personList, int id) {
    for (Person person : personList) {
        if (person.getId() == id)
            return person;
    }
}
```